# How to load external JSON data from a Web API in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

I am trying to create a Pie chart with the result of Web API and have Poly lines and Legends.`

I got the below code and working fine with random data.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    body {
        font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        width: 960px;
        height: 500px;
        position: relative;
    }

    svg {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    path.slice {
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    polyline {
        opacity: .3;
        stroke: black;
        stroke-width: 2px;
        fill: none;
    }
</style>
<body>
    Duration: 0<input type="range" id="duration" min="0" max="5000">5000
    <br>
    <button class="randomize">randomize</button>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/d3.js"></script>
    <script>

var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .append("g")

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "slices");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "labels");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "lines");

var width = 960,
    height = 450,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .sort(null)
    .value(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.8)
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.4);

var outerArc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius * 0.9)
    .outerRadius(radius * 0.9);

svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");

var key = function(d){ return d.data.label; };

var color = d3.scale.category20()
    .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", "elit", "sed", "do", "eiusmod", "tempor", "incididunt"])
    //.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

function randomData (){
    var labels = color.domain();
    return labels.map(function(label){
        return { label: label, value: Math.random() }
    }).filter(function() {
        return Math.random() > .5;
    }).sort(function(a,b) {
        return d3.ascending(a.label, b.label);
    });
}

change(randomData());

d3.select(".randomize")
    .on("click", function(){
        change(randomData());
    });

function mergeWithFirstEqualZero(first, second){
    var secondSet = d3.set(); second.forEach(function(d) { secondSet.add(d.label); });

    var onlyFirst = first
        .filter(function(d){ return !secondSet.has(d.label) })
        .map(function(d) { return {label: d.label, value: 0}; });
    return d3.merge([ second, onlyFirst ])
        .sort(function(a,b) {
            return d3.ascending(a.label, b.label);
        });
}

function change(data) {
    var duration = +document.getElementById("duration").value;
    var data0 = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data().map(function(d) { return d.data });
    if (data0.length == 0) data0 = data;
    var was = mergeWithFirstEqualZero(data, data0);
    var is = mergeWithFirstEqualZero(data0, data);

    /* ------- SLICE ARCS -------*/

    var slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pie(was), key);

    slice.enter()
        .insert("path")
        .attr("class", "slice")
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.data.label); })
        .each(function(d) {
            this._current = d;
        });

    slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pie(is), key);

    slice
        .transition().duration(duration)
        .attrTween("d", function(d) {
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            var _this = this;
            return function(t) {
                _this._current = interpolate(t);
                return arc(_this._current);
            };
        });

    slice = svg.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    slice
        .exit().transition().delay(duration).duration(0)
        .remove();

    /* ------- TEXT LABELS -------*/

    var text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
        .data(pie(was), key);

    text.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.data.label;
        })
        .each(function(d) {
            this._current = d;
        });

    function midAngle(d){
        return d.startAngle + (d.endAngle - d.startAngle)/2;
    }

    text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
        .data(pie(is), key);

    text.transition().duration(duration)
        .style("opacity", function(d) {
            return d.data.value == 0 ? 0 : 1;
        })
        .attrTween("transform", function(d) {
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            var _this = this;
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                _this._current = d2;
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return "translate("+ pos +")";
            };
        })
        .styleTween("text-anchor", function(d){
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                return midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? "start":"end";
            };
        });

    text = svg.select(".labels").selectAll("text")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    text
        .exit().transition().delay(duration)
        .remove();

    /* ------- SLICE TO TEXT POLYLINES -------*/

    var polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
        .data(pie(was), key);

    polyline.enter()
        .append("polyline")
        .style("opacity", 0)
        .each(function(d) {
            this._current = d;
        });

    polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
        .data(pie(is), key);

    polyline.transition().duration(duration)
        .style("opacity", function(d) {
            return d.data.value == 0 ? 0 : .5;
        })
        .attrTween("points", function(d){
            this._current = this._current;
            var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
            var _this = this;
            return function(t) {
                var d2 = interpolate(t);
                _this._current = d2;
                var pos = outerArc.centroid(d2);
                pos[0] = radius * 0.95 * (midAngle(d2) < Math.PI ? 1 : -1);
                return [arc.centroid(d2), outerArc.centroid(d2), pos];
            };
        });

    polyline = svg.select(".lines").selectAll("polyline")
        .data(pie(data), key);

    polyline
        .exit().transition().delay(duration)
        .remove();
};

    </script>
</body>
```

But I want to call the data from my Web API below.Can some one please guide on the process as I am completely new to D3 and also Jquery/Javascript.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "api/PieChart",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
```

Answer (score 3):

**d3.js** has an excellent API to fetch remote data from a WEB API.

It's documented here: https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Requests

Among other functions there are convenience functions like `d3.json` and `d3.csv` but also more low level functions like `d3.xhr`.

So **no need for jQuery** here.

Comment: I would like to connect to my SQL DB on demand and pull the data rather than maintaining a JSON file..

Comment: Well, that would be a totally different question on Stackoverflow.